# TinyMCE getting all editors and setting

Tags: javascript, jquery, tinymce

Good day,

I am trying to make a script that iterates through all editors (and in the end fetches all content and saves it) with TinyMCE and replaces their content.

However this only works for the first editor but not for the next one.

```
    for (var i = 0; i < tinymce.editors.length; i++) {
    var editorInstance = tinymce.editors[i];
    editorInstance.setContent('I have changed the content of this editor!');
}
```

Not really sure what I am doing wrong.

My HTML code is :

```
<textarea id="mytextarea" class="editor" name="editor[156]"></textarea>
<textarea id="mytextarea" class="editor" name="editor[172]"></textarea>
<textarea id="mytextarea" class="editor" name="editor[173]"></textarea>
<textarea id="mytextarea" class="editor" name="editor[174]"></textarea>
```

To my own logic this should work. (*but it doesn't ;-) *)

I tried it also differently :

```
$("#editorsection .editor").each(function () {
    console.log('editor found method #1');
    var Content = tinyMCE.$(this).getContent();
    console.log('obtained content : ' + Content);
});
```

But also to no avail.

I hope that someone could tell me what I am doing wrong. Thanks in advance!

---

### Solution as suggested by : Michael Fromin

**HTML code :**

```
<textarea class="editor" name="editor[156]"></textarea>
<textarea class="editor" name="editor[172]"></textarea>
<textarea class="editor" name="editor[173]"></textarea>
<textarea class="editor" name="editor[174]"></textarea>
```

**Javascript / JQuery code**

```
function SaveContent(){
    console.log('ajax save content button clicked');
    console.log(tinymce.editors.length + ' : TinyMCE editors found.');

    var editorContent = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < tinymce.editors.length; i++) {
        var editorInstance = tinymce.editors[i];
        var content = editorInstance.getContent();
        editorContent.push( content );
        console.log('editor : ' + i + ' has content set : ' + content );
    }

    console.log('obtained content : ' + editorContent);

    ///######## SENDING THE INFORMATION BY AJAX
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "?ajaxcall=quicksave",
        data: {
            'content': editorContent,
            'page': 5
        },
        ///######## IN CASE OF SUCCESS
        success: function (response) {
            if(response !== ''){
                alert('error : ' + response);
            }
        }
    }
    );
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot have multiple items on one page with the same `id` - that is invalid HTML.

If you change each `textarea` to have its own `id` things should start working.

This fiddle shows a working example:  http://fiddle.tinymce.com/Ujgaab/2

Comment: Indeed that duplicate ID was a small error I have overlooked. The other part. Thanks!! Just what I needed!! And maybe it actually was caused by the duplicate ID. But in the end the problem has been solved. Thanks to you!